# Java8 time comparison in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, java-time, type-mismatch, datetime-comparison

I stumbled across some strange behaviour when comparing Java8 time objects.
The below does not appear to be valid code.

```
val t1 = LocalTime.now()
val t2 = LocalTime.now()
val foo: Int = t1 > t2
```

Yet hovering over the undersquiggled code shows that the overridden function return type is correct:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: `t1 > t2` returns a boolean. The `>` operator uses `compareTo` under the hood, but it's not `compareTo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, when using the natively overloaded operators (comparison operators specifically) - Kotlin doesn't just call `compareTo` but rather performs a `compareTo` against 0 (thus ending up as a bool).

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#comparison-operators

> #### Comparison operators
>
> | Expression | Translated to |
> | --- | --- |
> | `a > b` | `a.compareTo(b) > 0` |
> | `a < b` | `a.compareTo(b) < 0` |
> | `a >= b` | `a.compareTo(b) >= 0` |
> | `a <= b` | `a.compareTo(b) <= 0` |
>
> All comparisons are translated into calls to `compareTo`, that is required to return `Int`.

The documentation snippet you attached is admittedly a bit confusing.